# Retriving a variable stored in cached page

Tags: jsp, caching

I have a variable called 'line' which has a value 'true'( tag) in a (sample.jsp)jsp page which is been cached intentionally. Now i want to retrieve the value stored in 'line' variable in some other jsp in which sample.jsp is imported. But since the page is cached i am not able to get the expected value. How to get this value? Please help.

Comment: Looks like a workaround. Dynamic pages should never be cached. Did you run into this problem and like to hack a workaround?

Comment: Can you add the variable to your session? http://www.jsptut.com/sessions.jsp